# Representing application navigation

Tags: language-agnostic, configuration, navigation, computer-science

I have a complex application with many pages.

Each page can have many possible routes to other pages: 'A' can go to 'B' or 'C', 'B' can go to 'A' but not 'C'. etc.

Rather than embed this "where to go to next" logic in each page (horror!) I of course want to encapsulate it in a main point of control. 'A' doesn't need to know about 'B' or 'C'.

Even better, I'd like to reduce the problem to a matter of configuration.

This isn't a language/framework specific question -- it's a matter of how best (simple, pragmatic) to represent and interpret Workflow logic.

**Has anyone had experience representing a complex flow between points in an application as a configurable setting?**

Comment: Configurable for the user or the developer? And is this for a web application or software?

Comment: Are you talking about GUI? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: For both questions -- configurable by whom? and GUI ? -- if it's done right, it shouldn't matter since it'd be *conceptually* represented largely the same either way. If it was to be configurable by a user, it'd just be a matter surfacing the map/configuration -- whatever it is -- to a user for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is a pretty classic [Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine). You have States (Pages), Navigation (Transitions), but also you can have things like entry/exit actions and transition conditions.

With that said, it's worth thinking about your navigation, do you simply want a list of navigation options dynamically added to the page, or is there some extra smarts involved. Think of *when* the navigation is valid, *what* information is required for the navigation, the *data* you might want to bring with you to the next navigation etc.

I've created state maps before by simply using XML, eg:

```
<states>
  <state name="Open">
    <transition action="Close" state="Closed" />
  </state>
  <state name="Closed">
    <transition action="Open" state="Open" />
    <transition action="Lock" state="Locked" />
  </state>
  <state name="Locked">
    <transition action="Unlock" state="Closed" />
  </state>
</states>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use something like the .NET work flow foundation to represent this neatly.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a state machine, where each page represents a state and the transitions are stored in your configuration. Google for that, you'll get samples which may help.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much every Web Application framework has to tackle this problem.  For java, take a look at Struts2, Spring MVC, Tapestry, Wicket, etc. to see the various approaches.  (XML is naturally a common method of capturing the transition information in an external config file.)

Answer (score 0):

[Press On](http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csharold/presson/Site/press%20on.html) covers this sort of thing in some depth. (Using explicit representations of state machines and statecharts in design and implementation of user interfaces.)